# Run Jquery In Chrome Extension Action When User Clicks Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, google-chrome-extension

On my company's internal ticket tracking website, we have a form that we use to update or note changes in the ticket. When a client updates the ticket, I need to modify a text area, input, and click submit. I want to create a single button that will handle this repetitive task using a chrome extension.

In my extensions content.js script, I have the following which isn't getting the job done.

```
var blueButtonDom = document.createElement('a');
blueButtonDom.setAttribute('href','#');
blueButtonDom.setAttribute('onClick','clickHandler();return true');

function clickHandler() {
    $('textarea[id$="PrivateNotes"]').val('blue');
    $('input[id$="BillTime"]').val('1');
    $('input[id$="btnSave2"]').click();
}
```

Any input from you all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much,

Joe Chin

Comment: So are you using jQuery?

Comment: @climbage, I am using jquery. It was loaded through manifest.json's "content_scripts" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $myLink = $('<a href="#">Automagical</a>');

    $myLink.click(function() {
        $('#PrivateNotes').val('blue')
        $('#BillTime').val('1');
        $form.submit();
    });

    $('#myForm').prepend($myLink);
});
```

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <textarea id="PrivateNotes"></textarea>
    <input id="BillTime" type="text" />
    <input id="btnSave2" type="submit" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/T9bgw/

**UPDATED** to include $(document).ready()

Comment: This works, however, I seem to be having problems getting it to work in the context of a Chrome Extension. When I load it through a content script and a user clicks on it, the page says the function is undefined.

Comment: are you wrapping the jQuery in a document [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function?

Comment: Wrapping it in a .ready() function doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks.